# Issues trying to perform a Bamboo build via a HTTP Request

Tags: bamboo

I'm trying to trigger a Bamboo build using the following HTTP Request:

```
http://11.11.11.108:8085/rest/api/latest/queue/TCCONT530JAVA7UPGD-TCCONT530JAVA7UPGD?os_authType=basic
```

I keep getting the response:

```
HTTP ERROR 405

Problem accessing /rest/api/latest/queue/TCCONT530JAVA7UPGD-TCCONT530JAVA7UPGD. Reason:

Method Not Allowed
```

I have search around and haven't found any solution.  The only information I came across was something about adding the correct POST or GET.

Any help would be great.

Eric

Comment: so are you doing a POST or a GET?

Answer (score 2):

Reading the [Bamboo REST Resources](https://developer.atlassian.com/display/BAMBOODEV/Bamboo+REST+Resources) document states that it should be a POST like so:

```
curl -X POST --user admin:admin http://host:8085/rest/api/latest/queue/PLAN-KEY?os_authType=basic
```

If you are in a browser just trying to hit the URL then you are performing a GET which is why you would be getting 405 Method Not Allowed message.

If you want to try from a Browser get a REST Client Plugin like [Advanced REST Client](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo) for Chrome or [RESTClient](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/restclient/) for Firefox.

Answer (score 2):

Earlier I was getting the same error.I was using postman.
Changing http to https, triggered the build just fine

Comment: Let me know if more details are required